# How to send custom header in C# (Xamarin) with HttpRequestMessage with the exactly defined names?

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

I need to send Http request with my custom headers to a server code which runs on PHP.

**I use the following code for this:**

preparedAddress is string url; AuthenticationLine and dateValue are defined string values too. 'json' variable contains prepared string

**Here is code:**

```
client = new HttpClient();
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
int _TimeoutSec = 90;
client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, _TimeoutSec);
string _ContentType = "application/json";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));
var uri = new Uri(String.Format(preparedAddress));
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage msgToSend = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
//my custom headers
        msgToSend.Headers.Add("SN-Authentication", AuthenticationLine);
        msgToSend.Headers.Add("SN-Date", dateValue);
 var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(_ContentType);
 msgToSend.Content = content;
 HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = client.SendAsync(msgToSend).Result;
        String execResult = response.ReasonPhrase;
```

On php side I have the following obtained data:

```
Array (     
[HTTP_SN_AUTHENTICATION] => Array ( [0] => my data 1 )      
[HTTP_SN_DATE] => Array ( [0] => my data 2 )
```

Additional headers which were not set explicitly, But I do not care about them.

Why C# changed header names? How to make C# send headers with names I have defined?

Comment: If you run the request via Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), what is the header name there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my PHP code, there was a little mistake with headers processing.

I appreciate the advice to use Fiddler tool. I have used a similar tool - Postman, and PHP displayed headers in the same format as if the request was sent from C# code. And the PHP framework recognized and processed headers as expected.

Case is closed...